# bitmask enumerations in objective-c or C

Tags: iphone, c

I'm trying to draw a line, broken out into segments dependent on values.  For example, if there are 5 fields, and all 5 fields were true, then my Line would look like

```
-----
```

If say the first and last fields were true, and everything else would be false, then it would be

```
-   -
```

I thought I could do this with a bit mask of some sort.  First of all, I've never done a bit mask before, but I think I've seen them here and there.  I was wondering how I could go about this, and use enumerations instead of 1/0 for readability.  As far as I can see from my data, I would only need values of either 1 or 0 for the different properties.   However, it would be good to know how to have one of the values be a three level or higher enumeration for future reference.  Thanks!

Trying to do something like:

```
enum CodingRegions {
    Coding = 0x01,
    NonCoding = 0x02
};

enum Substitution {
    Synonymous = 0x04,
    NonSynonmous = 0x05
};
```

Then based on the value of the object, I could do

```
bitmask???? = object.CodingRegion | object.Substitution;
```

Then later, check the value of the bitmask somehow, and then draw the line accordingly based on what the values are.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth Thanks for the link.  The science makes sense, but I'm not sure how to do get the values out with text.  Like the article says, I can manually AND something and check for that status bit, but I was wondering how to do it with text so I don't have to do the values.

Comment: Why not just use an `char[]` that stores `' '` and `'-'`? I doubt the overhead would be significant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want, but:

```
// assumed Coding/NonCoding, Synonomous/NonSynonymous are opposites of each other. If not, add more bit fields

enum CodingRegions 
{
    Coding = 1 << 0
} ;

enum Substitution
{
    Synonymous = 1 << 1
}

void PrintBitmask( NSUInteger bitmask )
{
    printf( "%s", bitmask & Coding != 0 ? "-" : " " ) ;
    printf( "%s", bitmask & Substitution != 0 ? "-" : " " ) ;

    printf( "\n" ) ;
}
```

Your `PrintBitmask()` could also look like this:

```
void PrintBitmask( NSUInteger bitmask )
{
    printf( "%s", bitmask & Coding != 0 ? "Coding" : "Noncoding" ) ;
    printf( "|" ) ;
    printf( "%s", bitmask & Substitution != 0 ? "Synonymous-" : "Nonsynonymous" ) ;

    printf( "\n" ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what your requirements are, but here is one way it might be written in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum MyField_ {
  hasWombat        = 1 << 0,
  hasTrinket       = 1 << 1,
  hasTinRoof       = 1 << 2,
  hasThreeWheels   = 1 << 3,
  myFieldEnd       = 1 << 4,
} MyField;

void printMyField(MyField data) {
  MyField field = 1;
  while (field != myFieldEnd) {
    printf("%c", data & field ? '-' : ' ');
    field <<= 1;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  MyField data = hasTrinket | hasThreeWheels;
  printMyField(data);
  data |= hasWombat; // set a field
  data &= ~hasTrinket; // clear a field
  printMyField(data);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should probably use `putchar` rather than the elaborate `printf %c` business.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* I prefer macros over enums (at least for something this simple) */
#define SPACE 0x0
#define DASH  0x1

/* input fields */
int fields[5] = {DASH,SPACE,SPACE,SPACE,DASH};

/* create bitmask */
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    mask |= (fields[i] << i);
}

/* interpret bitmask and print the line */
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    if (mask & (fields[i] << i)) {
        printf("%c", '-');
    } else {
        printf("%c", ' ');
    }
}
```